# NSS error -12276 SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN- tornado (verify=False)

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tornado

I am trying to enable SSL for the `CURL` command (that is I want my CURL command to work without `-k/--insecure` argument).

At present, My code is working with `HTTPS` (from the browser) and through the `CURL` command It is working with the `-k` option.(Sonar Qube is reporting the below code as vulnerability and suggesting to change `verify=False` to `Verify=True`).

**Current code line:**

```
response = requests.post(url,
                         data=json.dumps(req_body),
                         verify=False,
                         headers=headers)
```

with the above code below CURL command is working fine.

```
curl -k -v  -X POST https://k8's_svc-IP:443/v3/history/data -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "userName: admin" -H "source: console"  -d '{"user_name": "admin", "token": "abcdd12345"}'
```

**Changes in code** (verify=True):

```
response = requests.post(url,
                             data=json.dumps(req_body),
                             verify=True,
                             headers=headers)
```

So after verify=True now I am trying the CURL command without `-k` option but no luck getting below ERROR.

---

```
** NSS error -12276 (SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN)
* Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.*
```

---

I am new to SSL and any help on this would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *"requested domain name does not match the server's certificate"* - this means that the name you have in the URL *k8's_svc-IP* is not the name which is given in the certificate (likely a domain name like example.com is given there, not an IP address)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you. I got it but then how CURL -k is working and not giving an error. and you are right I can see CN=*.abc.example.com now how this will change my CURL command(shall I remove IP address and use this domain then what about different endpoint for example /v3/data/status how to connect it with domain name). Thanks!.

Comment: `curl -k` is basically `verify=False`.